# What multiplier does a "Perfect!" chain give me?

Tags: battle-gems-adventurequest

In *[Battle Gems (AdventureQuest)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/battle-gems-adventurequest/id694721552?mt=8)*, you increase the damage of an attack if you use all the gems from a connected section (referred to as "Perfect").

How much does it increase?  At what point is it better to create a larger patch that you cannot cover perfectly than a smaller one you can?